# Xcode Table View with NSMutableArray of Objects

Tags: objective-c

I have a Table view with its view controller and i am trying to fill this table with some data from a NSMutableArray.

I have a class called Lugar.m and Lugar.h, with some properties (with the @synthesize in the .m file) as i show:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *nombre;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *direccion;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *descripcion;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *precio;
```

Then I have the controller of the table view with the following viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title =@"Comer";
Lugar *lugar = [[Lugar alloc] init];
self.datosTabla = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];
NSArray *nombres = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Masala",@"Italiano",@"Gaia",@"Pekaditos",@"Ojeda",@"Plan B", nil];
NSArray *direcciones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"C/San Roque, 5", @"C/ Moneda, 7 ",@"C/Nueva, 6", @"C/San Roque, 5", @"C/ Moneda, 7 ",@"C/Nueva, 6", nil];
NSArray *descripciones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bonito restaurante ecologico",@"Restaurante fino y caro", @"El mejor marisco de burgos",@"Calida recio mud", @"Calidad insuperable" , @"Calidad insuperable",nil];
NSArray *precios = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"25€", @"15€", @"12€", @"6€", @"34€", @"34€",nil];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
lugar.nombre = [nombres objectAtIndex:i];
lugar.direccion = [direcciones objectAtIndex:i];
lugar.descripcion = [descripciones objectAtIndex:i];
lugar.precio = [precios objectAtIndex:i];
[self.datosTabla insertObject:lugar atIndex:i];
}
```

In this file i have also the cellForRowAtIndex

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    Lugar *tempName =[self.datosTabla objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempName.nombre;
    }
    return cell;
    }
```

I have also the methods that return the rows and the sections

The app runs properly but it shows me just the name of the last object add to the mutableArray, in this case the restaurant called: Plan B. So i have just get a table with 6 rows with the same restaurant information.

I tried to fix it and i spend a lot of hours with no result.
I would thank any help.
Thanks in advance
Luis

PD: the information of the arrays is in Spanish, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting the same object into the `datosTabla` array 5 times. Even though you are changing the properties of the `lugar` object on each iteration of the for-loop, the pointer that points to the `lugar` object is not changing.

Make sure you allocate the `lugar` object inside the for-loop so there are 5 distinct objects.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title =@"Comer";
    self.datosTabla = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];
    NSArray *nombres = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Masala",@"Italiano",@"Gaia",@"Pekaditos",@"Ojeda",@"Plan B", nil];
    NSArray *direcciones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"C/San Roque, 5", @"C/ Moneda, 7 ",@"C/Nueva, 6", @"C/San Roque, 5", @"C/ Moneda, 7 ",@"C/Nueva, 6", nil];
    NSArray *descripciones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bonito restaurante ecologico",@"Restaurante fino y caro", @"El mejor marisco de burgos",@"Calida recio mud", @"Calidad insuperable" , @"Calidad insuperable",nil];
    NSArray *precios = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"25€", @"15€", @"12€", @"6€", @"34€", @"34€",nil];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Lugar *lugar = [[Lugar alloc] init];
        lugar.nombre = [nombres objectAtIndex:i];
        lugar.direccion = [direcciones objectAtIndex:i];
        lugar.descripcion = [descripciones objectAtIndex:i];
        lugar.precio = [precios objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.datosTabla insertObject:lugar atIndex:i];
    }
}
```

You need to populate the cell's text field every time that method is called, not just when cell == nil.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Lugar *tempName =[self.datosTabla objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempName.nombre;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it still doesnt work fine. It just show me the last restaurant. Any ideas?

Comment: I overlooked the source of the issue, I've updated my answer with both issues and fixes.